# Как правильно переделать клиентский скрипт, под сервер NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот сам код клиентский, его нужно переделать под библиотеку что бы подключить его на сервере NodeJS

```
(function () {

var t = {};

window.containsMat = function (text) {
    return t.containsMat(text);
};

window.antimat = t;

t.badPatterns = [
    "^к(о|а)зел$",
];

t.goodPatterns = [
    ".*психу.*",
];

t.goodWords = [
    "дезмонда",
    "застрахуйте",
    "одномандатный",
    "подстрахуй",
    "психуй"
];

t.letters = {
    "a": "а",
    "b": "в",
    "c": "с",
    "e": "е",
    "f": "ф",
    "g": "д",
    "h": "н",
    "i": "и",
    "k": "к",
    "l": "л",
    "m": "м",
    "n": "н",
    "o": "о",
    "p": "р",
    "r": "р",
    "s": "с",
    "t": "т",
    "u": "у",
    "v": "в",
    "x": "х",
    "y": "у",
    "w": "ш",
    "z": "з",
    "ё": "е",
    "6": "б",
    "9": "д"
};

t.containsMat = function (text) {

    text = t.cleanBadSymbols(text.toLowerCase());

    var words = text.split(" ");

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        var word = t.convertEngToRus(words[i]);

        if (t.isInGoodWords(word) && t.isInGoodPatterns(word))
            continue;

        if (t.isInBadPatterns(word))
            return true;
    }

    if (t.containsMatInSpaceWords(words))
        return true;

    return false;
};

t.convertEngToRus = function (word) {
    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
        for (var key in t.letters) {
            if (word.charAt(j) == key)
                word = word.substring(0, j) + t.letters[key] + word.substring(j + 1, word.length)
        }
    }

    return word;
};

t.cleanBadSymbols = function (text) {
    return text.replace(/[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Яё0-9\s]/g, "");
};

t.isInGoodWords = function (word) {

    for (var i = 0; i < t.goodWords.length; i++) {
        if (word == t.goodWords[i])
            return true;
    }

    return false;
};

t.isInGoodPatterns = function (word) {

    for (var i = 0; i < t.goodPatterns.length; i++) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(t.goodPatterns[i]);
        if (pattern.test(word))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
};

t.isInBadPatterns = function (word) {

    for (var i = 0; i < t.badPatterns.length; i++) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(t.badPatterns[i]);
        if (pattern.test(word))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
};

t.containsMatInSpaceWords = function (words) {
    var spaceWords = t.findSpaceWords(words);

    for (var i = 0; i < spaceWords.length; i++) {

        var word = t.convertEngToRus(spaceWords[i]);

        if (t.isInBadPatterns(word))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
};

t.findSpaceWords = function (words) {

    var out = [];
    var spaceWord = "";

    for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++ ){
        var word = words[i];

        if(word.length <= 3){
            spaceWord += word;
            continue;
        }

        if(spaceWord.length >= 3){
            out.push(spaceWord);
            spaceWord = "";
        }
    }

    return out;
};

t.addBadPattern = function (pattern) {
    t.badPatterns.push(pattern);
};

t.addGoodPattern = function (pattern) {
    t.goodPatterns.push(pattern);
};

t.addGoodWord = function (pattern) {
    t.goodWords.push(pattern);
};
  })();
```

Comment: что?  не понял    вас

Comment: что-нибудь пробовал сам?

Comment: да но не выходило, ведь window это же клиентский параметр

Comment: что именно делал?

Comment: пробовал в место window jquery юзать, но не работало, я не силен в js..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Nodejs любой js файл может быть использован в качестве [модуля](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

При этом у него есть два важных свойства:

1. Своя область видимости - переменные объявленные внутри модуля с помощью ключевого слова `var` добавляются в модуль, а не в глобальный объект.
2. Публичные поля/методы - с помощью [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) можно указать поля/методы, которые могут вызывать пользователи этого модуля.

---

Если посмотреть на предоставленный код, можно заметить следующее:

1. Область видимости ограничена самовызывающейся функцией
2. в глобальный объект window добавляются публичные методы *модуля*.

Как можно заметить, пункты похожы на приведенные выше.

Так как в модуле область видимости уже ограничена - нужно убрать самовызывающуюся функцию.
Далее останется просто заменить экспорт через window, на экспорт через exports.

В итоге получится что-то вроде этого:

```
var t = {};

exports.containsMat = function (text) {
    return t.containsMat(text);
};

exports.antimat = t;

// далее код без изменений
```

---

Пусть даннй код хранится в файле `myModule.js`, тогда использовать его можно так:

```
var myModule = require('./myModule.js');

// ... может быть другой код ...

var message = ""; // get from somewhere
if(myModule.containsMat(message)){
  // obscene detected
}
```

Comment: а далее при отправке, как?  if(exports.containsMat(message)){
      // obscene detected
   }

Comment: @Members, при какой отправке?

Comment: вот смотри на гитхабе этот модуль, https://github.com/itlessons/js-antimat я имел ввиду у нас прилетает с клиента сообщения далее мы проверяем этот контент на нахождение матерных слове если есть отправляем одно, если нету то другое

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dTqCQGYx правильно?

Comment: спасибо большое, получилось

Comment: @Members, первые три строчки: `const EventEmitter = require('events');
 
exports = new EventEmitter();` не нужны

Comment: да уже понял) спасибо большое разобрался